# NoReverseMatch implementing django-likes

Tags: django

Getting the following error when trying to install django-likes

NoReverseMatch at /post/25/

Reverse for '' with arguments '('posts-post', 25, 1)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Exception Location:     /Users/Pete/.virtualenvs/innerlocal-mvp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 463

I'm not sure where to even start on this error, I've done a lot of searching, but nothing comes up.

My view that this is referring to:

```
def single_post(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    ...

    return render(request, 'posts/single_post.html', locals())
```

with {% likes post %} in the html.

and this line highlighted from the resulting html:

```
<a class="liker" href="{% url like content_type content_obj.id 1 %}" rel="nofollow">{% trans "I Like" %}</a>
```

I'm using Django 1.7 so wouldn't be surprised if that was a problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Extra settings as requested:

the urls.py lines (first, the app, second, the django-likes url:

```
url(r'^', include('posts.urls')),
(r'^likes/', include('likes.urls')),
```

and the urls.py for the posts app:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from views import PostDelete

urlpatterns = patterns('posts.views',
     # (r'^', 'home'),
     url(r'^$', 'all_posts', name='home'),
     url(r'^post/(?P<id>\w+)/$', 'single_post', name='single_post'),
     url(r'^new-post/$', 'new_post', name='new_post'),
     url(r'^search/$', 'search', name='search'),
     url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDelete.as_view(),
         name='entry_delete'),
)
```

Installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    ....
    'secretballot',
    'likes',
)
```

Middleware classes:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'pipeline.middleware.MinifyHTMLMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
    'secretballot.middleware.SecretBallotIpMiddleware',
    'secretballot.middleware.SecretBallotIpUseragentMiddleware',
    'likes.middleware.SecretBallotUserIpUseragentMiddleware',
)
```

Template context processors:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)
```

Comment: How did you integrate django-likes to your project? Add INSTALLED_APPS, MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS settings to your question. Add also urls.py where you include django-likes urls to yours.

Comment: Your problem is with the urls, could you please show your urls.py ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I have added in the extra info, let me know what else I can supply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the app code needed a change:

In likes.html

from

```
<a class="liker" href="{% url like content_type content_obj.id 1 %}" rel="nofollow">{% trans "I Like" %}</a>
```

to

```
<a class="liker" href="{% url 'like' content_type content_obj.id 1 %}" rel="nofollow">{% trans "I Like" %}</a>
```

ie - the quotation marks around 'like'